# how to identify if rhel 7 machine requires reboot after kernel update

Tags: rhel, kernel, linux-kernel, grub

as all know after kernel upgrade (on `RHEL 7`), reboot is necessary in order to update the kernel version

So after reboot we can verify the kernel version by `uname -r`

since we are using scripts for kernel upgrade,

we want to verify what is the right approach that machines are required reboot as results of kernel upgrade

just to mention that `reboot` process isn't immediately after kernel upgrade process, and could be couple of months after kernel upgrade

so, we want to find the right verification that indicate that machine `RHEL7` required reboot

one approach is to verify by `uname -r` the version and comparing that version with installed rpm's as `rpm -qa | grep kernel`

but maybe we can get advice about better indication or better verification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as all know after kernel upgrade (on RHEL 7), reboot is necessary in order to update the kernel version

no, it's already upgraded; but to run a new kernel, you'll need to load the new kernel if you want to use it. Since Linux is not *that* cool, the only way to do that is effectively a reboot¹.

`yum` comes with a tool to tell you whether *any* of the things you've installed/upgraded require a reboot. Was easy to find, it's called `needs-restarting`. Call it with `-r` to get a meaningful return code.

---

¹ Technically, you could kexec into a new kernel, but none of the running processes, open files, filesystems network … will survive, so you end up with a broken state.

Comment: `kexec` has always been intriguing. Testing this with LAMP systems might not be a major problem window. Implementing on a production Oracle server gives me the willies.

Comment: well, you'd want to shut down as far as you can before you kexec, so terminate or CRIU all processes, unmount all file systems, or at least ro remount them… essentially, a shut down.

Comment: So essentially I would save the 2-3 minutes that the HPE server would take to verify the hardware/firmware. Not enough of an advantage to move away from a traditional `init 6`.

Comment: I mean, for server hardware with long initialization periods, doing the full reset certainly is annoying. I wonder whether systemd-boot would allow you to shut down and then actually kexec-boot back up...

Comment: If I have a system supporting Oracle databases and have a systemd service shutting down the instances in the case of a reboot, will the same scripts work when using kexec? Trying to be very conservative here since clinical data might be involved.

Comment: I don't know! I wish I knew.

Comment: @doneal24 I'll have to read https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/post/reboot-faster-with-kexec

Comment: @doneal24 Looks like systemd can do this out of the box: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/kexec#Systemd

Answer (score 1):

/usr/bin/needs-restarting (in yum-utils) can do this for you.

(e.g., `needs-restarting -r || shutdown +5 "Rebooting post patching"` )

```
Usage:  
    needs-restarting: Report a list of process ids of programs that started  
                    running before they or some component they use were  updated.  
  
  
Options:   
   -h, --help        show this help message and exit  
   -u, --useronly    show processes for my userid only  
   -r, --reboothint  only report whether a full reboot is required  
                     (exit code 1) or not (exit code 0)  
   -s, --services    list the affected systemd services only
```

Comment: The answer by Marcus Müller already mentioned `needs-starting`. Beat me to an answer by 30 seconds so I canceled mine. :(  The poster indicated that reboots may have to be delayed for possibly months so an automatic test to schedule a reboot is not what he's looking for.

Comment: @doneal24 sorry >.<